# Include directive in bazels BUILD file

Tags: bazel

I am using Bazel and have many `BUILD` files and would like to auto-generate parts. There are two options.

1) I create a `BUILD.template` file and replace the corresponding elements in the file and rename it back to `BUILD` after the generation is done.

.. or ..

2) I use an additional file like `BUILD.ext` and use an include directive inside the `BUILD` file which includes that given file. But I can't find any include support.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you can define your templates as [bazel macros](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html) in .bzl files, and `load` those macros in your BUILD files.